# How to calculate pricing

Tags: bmcc

I'm making films and videos for the past 3 years and now would like to go into a more professional enviroment.

One of the big tasks for this is to figure out pricing.

How do you calculate your price for videos? And do you openly write the price on your website, or do you ask the customer to take an offer?

I film on BMPCC4k, mostly wedding/event video, music video and maybe commercials.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, prices aren't a calculation, they are marketing and deal making.  You should do calculations on what a job will cost you before you bid it to make sure you can do it profitably enough to be worth your time, but ultimately, what you charge for a project is much more about the price you can demand for the work being done for the customer it's being done for.  If I'm doing a small video shoot for a small non-profit or a mom and pop business, my cost is going to be much lower per hour and per resource than if I'm doing a complicated shoot for a large commercial for a major business with deep pockets.

It's a complex interplay of what can be afforded, what is expected, what you are capable of delivering and what the customer needs.  The mom and pop shop can't afford that much and doesn't expect the world if they are a decent customer.  They don't need anywhere near my full capability, so it's a nice easy, low stress job that I can cut them a good deal on and get some filler.  A major corporation on the other hand is going to have much more rigorous demands, require a high degree of quality and I'll need to triple check my prep and work on the job.  They have deep pockets and are willing to pay for the attention and focus, so the job is going to cost them a lot more, even for the same time.

There is no magical equation to solve it for you.  It's business and you need to figure it out as you go by figuring out your market and adjusting your prices up or down for a given context based on if you are getting enough work in that segment of the market or not.  If you have too much work or want less of that segment, raise your prices.  If you have too little work or want to move more in to a segment, lower your prices.

Comment: We have three characteristics of every job: Good, Cheap, and Quick. Any given job can only have two characteristics. Let your customers choose.

Comment: The only thing I'd add is "Don't undercut yourself. Start at 15% higher than what you think you're worth."